# Can I install multiple Windows instance on the same computer?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-instances

I've finished building a new PC which will be used for development. As I have a full-time project for one major client and multiple small (hobby) projects for different small clients I want to separate the development environments.

Can I install 2 instances of Windows 8 Professional on the same computer (different drives or partitions)? (And I'm not talking about the license restrictions.)

*Bonus questions:*

- Can I share a 3th partition with both instances. If so, I suppose it best is a FAT32 partition?

  - Pro: No security issues (ownership, read-write permissions, ...)
  - Con: 4GB file limit
- I suppose it is not a problem to install a Linux instance next to those Windows instances, right?

Comment: No problems as long as you install Windows (multiple copies included) first and Linux last. While you can use something like EasyBCD (NeoGrub) in Windows (since installing Windows after Linux will wipe the latter's bootloader), installing Linux last will ensure that Grub2 takes over and handles all the OSes for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [native VDH Boot feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799282%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which was added with Windows 7. Convert the [WIM to a VHD](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-WindowsImageps1-0fe23a8f)

[image]

and [add it to the Boot Manager.](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). During boot you can now select the different OS version and they look and feel like real partitions, but the data are stored in a larger VHD, which you can easily backup and move to a different folder.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I'll have to take a better look at this as it might be a better solution (backup/moveable wise) than real partitions.

Comment: I'm currently trying out a VHD setup using the following instructions: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/dual-boot-windows-7-and-windows-8-using-a-vhd/6537. I'm using Windows 8 Professional as a "host", though!

Comment: @Niels R. which issue do you have? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible - and it probably will be automatic. Running them on seperate drives would probably the 'easiest' way, since each install's bootloader would be sitting on its own MBR, and you can select the OS off the bios, but you could definately run two installs of windows 8. Windows 8's bootloader is relatively new, so I chose to have my linux partition independantly from windows 8, but linux seems to chainload the windows 8 install fine.

Sharing a third partition wouldn't be an issue either, but really NTFS is the smart way to go there - I've never had much issues with a shared storage drive, and at worst, all you'd need to take control of the folder from the other instance of windows. It would be no different from having a external NTFS drive for data.

Comment: How can I be sure that a shared NTFS drive will not be causing problems (permissions-wise)? I once attached a virtual drive (NTFS) from one Virtual Machine to another VM and I couldn't see all data on it. I always blamed NTFS-permissions for that problem, but I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: well, I have an external shared drive and that's never happened ever

Comment: Could it be that Windows treats external drives differently than internal drives? E.g. you can't format an internal drive as exFAT while it allows it to do so with an external drive.

Answer (score 1):

You may install linux as a second OS on your machine any time. Bootlooder will be managed via grub, which is part of the linux.
Of course you can install an additional Windows 8 on a different hard drive with ease. To do that just unplug your hard drive with the first Windows 8 on it. After installing the second one just configure Windows 8 boot options (e.g. http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-bcdedit.htm ).
Linux reads and writes windows partitions without problems (fat, fat32, ntfs).

So summa summarum you can do!

Btw, I would recommend a Virtual Machine install first, also. There is VirtualBox from Oracle and VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Any virtual machine to help you. VirtualBox, VmWare ...

Ok, use [BootStar bootmanager](http://www.star-tools.com/english/) - 15 primary partition on 1 HDD, boot menu.

Comment: I don't want to use Virtual Machines as I want all the resources available for the development environment I'm working in at that moment. I've lots of experience with Virtual Machines, but as wonderful as they are, they have limitations too...

Comment: @NielsR. See link, may bee it better ...

Answer (score 0):

Besides that what you ask is really possible, why do you need different windows instances on the same PC for separating projects?

why do not really separate projects, or implement some version management strategy where you can check out/in the project that you want, when you want, where you want even from separated repositories...

Comment: I use git for version management.  I like to have different Windows environments because I need to install specific tools/SDKs/... for different clients/jobs. When a project at a client is finished I like to backup and discard the environment in it's whole.

Comment: I see, why not a native Hypervisor with the instances of windows you want as a development PC?...